# Regex optional matches pattern

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use the `?` quantifier to match a pattern only if it exists, but I can't get it working as I want. In the example below I'm trying to extract pair of digits following `AZA` and `ZZZ` where `ZZZ` appears all the time, but `AZA` is optional. When `AZA` is missing, I just want to return a `('', [zzz-value])` pair (empty string instead of the `AZA` value):

Input:

```
AZA:00zx---
ZZZ:32fd---
testxfiler
gsdkfklsd
fdsfsk
AZA:06x---
ZZZ:50----
gsdkfklsd
gsdkfklsd
fdsfsk
fdsfsk
gsdkfklsd
fdsfsk
ZZZ:32zzz----
fdsfsk
fdsfsk
gsdkfklsd
fdsfsk
AZA:46----
ZZZ:53---
```

Desired output:

```
[(00,32), (06, 50), ('',32), (46,53)]
```

My attempt:

```
re.findall('(?:AZA:([0-9]*))?.*?ZZZ:([0-9]*)', text, re.DOTALL)
```

My output:

```
[('00', '32'), ('', '50'), ('', '32'), ('', '53')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?:AZA:(\d+).*?)?ZZZ:(\d+)
```

See [**demo**](http://regex101.com/r/bB8jY7/5)

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(?:AZA:(\d+).*?)?ZZZ:(\d+)', re.DOTALL)
test_str = u"AZA:00zx---\nZZZ:32fd---\ntestxfiler\ngsdkfklsd\nfdsfsk\nAZA:06x---\nZZZ:50----\ngsdkfklsd\ngsdkfklsd\nfdsfsk\nfdsfsk\ngsdkfklsd\nfdsfsk\nZZZ:32zzz----\nfdsfsk\nfdsfsk\ngsdkfklsd\nfdsfsk\nAZA:46----\nZZZ:53---"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Could you please explain me briefly why this works and mine doesn't?

Comment: @confused00 your and this is same.Just that the placement of `?` differs.Yur `.*?` before `ZZZ` will consume the `AZA` part too as `AZA` is optional.That is why you are getting `\d+` of `ZZZ` and not of `AZA`.See http://regex101.com/r/bB8jY7/6

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add DOTALL modifier,

```
>>> text = """AZA:00zx---
ZZZ:32fd---
testxfiler
gsdkfklsd
fdsfsk
AZA:06x---
ZZZ:50----
gsdkfklsd
gsdkfklsd
fdsfsk
fdsfsk
gsdkfklsd
fdsfsk
ZZZ:32zzz----
fdsfsk
fdsfsk
gsdkfklsd
fdsfsk
AZA:46----
ZZZ:53---"""
>>> re.findall(r'(?:AZA:([0-9]+)[\S\s]*?)?ZZZ:([0-9]+)', text)
[('00', '32'), ('06', '50'), ('', '32'), ('46', '53')]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tF4jD3/17)

`[\S\s]*` would match any space or non-space characters zero or more times.

**Why your regex fails to work?**

```
(?:AZA:([0-9]*))?.*?ZZZ:([0-9]*)
```

We all know that in DOTALL mode, dot in the regex will match even line breaks also. So by making `(?:AZA:([0-9]*))?` as optional, the following `.*?` would match all the preceding characters which are present before `ZZZ:([0-9]*)`. So by including the following `.*?` into the preceding optional group makes `AZA:(\d+)` to match if it presents and the digits following `AZA:` would be captured. Now, it won't do an unnecessary match.

Comment: This solution assumes that if AZA exists, then it must be on adjacent line.

Comment: That actually is the case - they're on adjacent lines if they both show up. Thanks for the answer Avinash. I'll accept the first answer posted but I appreciate the help, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

A regex of the form

`(?:AZA:(\d+)[^\n]*\n)?(?:ZZZ:)(\d+)[^\n]*` would be helpfull.

For example

```
>>>re.findall('(?:AZA:(\d+)[^\n]*\n)?(?:ZZZ:)(\d+)[^\n]*' ,x)
[('00', '32'), ('06', '50'), ('', '32'), ('46', '53')]
```

- `(?:AZA:(\d+)[^\n]*\n)?` matches `:AZA:` followed by digits `\d+` followed by anything other than `\n`(`[^\n]`). The quantifier at the end `?` ensures that the entire group is optional. The digits are captured in group 1
- `(?:ZZZ:)(\d+)[^\n]*` matches `:ZZZ:` followed by digit `\d+` and anything other than `\n`. Digits captured in group 2

**What you missed**

`re.findall('(?:AZA:([0-9]*))?.*?ZZZ:([0-9]*)', text, re.DOTALL)`

the entire `(?:AZA:([0-9]*))?.*?` should have been made optional as

`(?:AZA:([0-9]*))?.*?)?`

followed by `\n`

changing your regex like

`re.findall('(?:AZA:([0-9]*).*?)?\nZZZ:([0-9]*)' ,x)`

will give output as

```
[('00', '32'), ('06', '50'), ('', '32'), ('46', '53')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the explanation, this works too. I'll accept the first answer posted that worked, but thank you for your help